# SpringBoot Web MVC Application cannot resolve JSP views

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to implement a web application using Springboot. but when I request methods I get 404 Error. Springboot cannot find Jsp files.

this is my Controller Code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/loginSuccess")
public ModelAndView loginSuccess() {
    System.out.println("in login success");
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}

@GetMapping(value = "/loginError")
public ModelAndView showLoginError() {
    System.out.println("in login error");
    return new ModelAndView("error");
}
```

and this is my SecurityConfig:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return  new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return new EmployeeDetailService(employeeRepository, passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .successForwardUrl("/loginSuccess")
                .failureUrl("/loginError")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

I also specified prefix and suffix in application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/static/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I also have these dependencies in my pom file:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

and this is my Project Structure:

[image]
can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Are your jsp files inside static folder only or /static/jsp

Comment: they're inside static folder only

Comment: Can you share your project structure from your IDE as a picture and state which version of the IDE you are using

Comment: I added a picture of my project Structure. I am using IntelliJ 2021.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main *template engines* for SpringBoot are Thymeleaf, Groovy, FreeMarker, Jade. In the reference guide:

> JSP should be avoided if possible, there are several known limitations
> when using them with embedded servlet containers.

> An executable jar will not work because of a hard coded file pattern
> in Tomcat.

If the JSPs are legacy or proprietary codes that you can't convert, you have to do a few things in order to develop/maintain, compile and kinda run a SpringBootApplication running them in Intellij:

1. maven: your pom must be a '**war**' package.
   That will makes intellij look for and compile the JSPs right.
2. web facet: put your .jsp files in a folder where they are expected to be in a webapp: **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/**
   The jsp will never be 'compiled'/'interpretable' in static.
3. spring facet: set the prefix to /WEB-INF/jsp/ in your **application.properties**
4. tomcat: have those dependencies:

> ```
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
>    <scope>provided</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
>    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
>    <scope>provided</scope>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> ```

5. build runnable war: make an Intellij "maven configuration" that run :

> clean install -f pom.xml

6. run that war: make an Intellij "jar configuration" with those settings:

- path to jar : <the path to the **war** file in the *target* folder>
- before launch : run the "maven configuration" you created

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem and for me specifying the web resource directory containing the JSP files resolved the issue.

1. open project structure and under modules -> web -> web resource directory specify the directory in which your view are contained (in this case `webapp`)
2. open `application.properties`
3. specify the folder within your webresource directory which contains your views as prefix (in this case `/views/`)
4. specify your view suffix `.jsp`

this should enable intelij to resolve the views returned by the controller.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have ultimate version of intellij, it was throwing me error saying **cannot resolve jsp**. Showing me warning. I created the module, specified the path. And it was working. Click on the + icon of web resource directory, and mention the path of your jsp file. It will work.